# How to set timeout for Next.js Serverless Function using TRPC?

Tags: next.js, vercel, trpc.io

In the NextJS dashboard I see calls to the serverless function `/api/trpc/dailyTrends.getDailyTrends`

I would like to set a custom timeout for it in the `vercel.json` file:

```
{
  "functions": {
    "api/trpc/routers/dailyTrends.ts": {
      "maxDuration": 1
    }
  }
}
```

but this leads to the error

```
Error: The pattern "api/trpc/routers/dailyTrends.ts" defined in `functions` doesn't match any Serverless Functions.
Learn More: https://vercel.link/unmatched-function-pattern
```

When I try to deploy to Vercel. I've played around with the naming a bunch, but confused on serverless function naming using TRPC. What's my actual function name?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to set it up via `vercel.json` file using different configurations, but nothing worked for me. I ended up bumping Next.js version to 13.5.X and setup the `maxDuration` value inside the `/api/trpc/[trpc].ts` endpoint

```
//All trpc functions can be run max for 300 seconds
export const config = {
  maxDuration: 300,
};

// export API handler
export default createNextApiHandler({
  router: appRouter,
  createContext: createTRPCContext,
});
```

This does not allow per router or per procedure configuration, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Vercel needs a fully qualified file path from the root directory. If you are using routes then it will not find it because it's looking for a file path.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."